# django-crispy-forms input size

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

According with [django-crispy-form documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms), I will be able to change input width with class `input-small`. But my form always looks with width at 100%:

[image]

Also, If I add css_class to Field the size remains at width:100% ( `.form-control` )

I have set form as documentation explains:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    usuari = forms.CharField( help_text = u'Codi Usuari')
    paraula_de_pas = forms.CharField( help_text = u'Paraula de pas')

    # Uni-form
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'  
    helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'  
    helper.layout = Layout(
        PrependedText('usuari', 
                      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ',  
                      css_class='input-small'),
        PrependedText('paraula_de_pas', 
                      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span> ', 
                      css_class='input-small'),
        FormActions(
            Submit('save_changes', 'Entrar-hi', css_class="btn-primary"),
        )
    )
```

In settings:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK="bootstrap3"
```

I'm up to date version. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In bootstrap3 class name for small input box is `input-sm`
- `input-sm` just sets size of the font and height of the field, it has nothing to do with  field width.

`form-horizontal`, `col-lg-2` and `col-lg-8` make horizontal layout for the form (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal). So first of all make sure your screen resolution to enough for `lg`. Try `col-sm-*`

Comment: All you say is true, but this don't solve my issue. I would like to reduce input width.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the size of the input fields, just use the Column() like so:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Column

helper.layout = Layout(
    Column(
        'usuari', 
        'paraula_de_pas',
    css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),

        FormActions(
            Submit('save_changes', 'Entrar-hi', css_class="btn-primary"),
        )
    )
```

This will create a column of the width you want using the css_class attribute , in my example, I am using col-md-4 mb-0